# Javascript Issue with Countdowns and Reloads

Tags: javascript

I have a small script that basically warns a user when their session is about to expire on the backend. At 10 minutes, it warns the user with a popup, and at a given time, the page SHOULD reload, sending the user to the login screen based on session expiring rules of the backend. Hence the reload rather than the redirect.

But this current script I am working with sometimes causes an issue where the page will just constantly cycle reloads shooting off requests at about 1 per second. My question is, is there anything I can do to freshen up this script to stop the page from doing 60 reload requests per minute and just fire the reload script once?

```
    var eventTime = 0;
        var currentTime = 0;
        var duration = 0;
        var sessionIsExpiring = false;
    
        function sessionCountdownTimerOutput(){
            // Time Out check
            if (duration.asSeconds() <= 30) {
                clearInterval();
                window.location.reload();
                console.log('logged out');
            }else if(!sessionIsExpiring && duration.asSeconds() > 0 && duration.asSeconds() <= 600){
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Session Expiring',
                    text: 'Looks like your session is expiring. Either reload the current page or conduct an action in order to extend it. After your session expires, you will be logged out.',
                    icon: 'error',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: 'btn btn-danger',
                    }
                });
                console.log('user almost logged out');
                sessionIsExpiring = true;
            }
    
            duration = moment.duration(duration.asSeconds() - 1, 'seconds');
            $('.timertext').text('Your session expires in ' + duration.hours()+ ' hour(s) ' + duration.minutes()+ ' minute(s) ' + duration.seconds() + ' second(s)');
        }

function sessionCountdownTimer(start){
        //eventTime = start;
        currentTime = moment().unix();
        var leftTime = eventTime - currentTime;//Now i am passing the left time from controller itself which handles timezone stuff (UTC), just to simply question i used harcoded values.
        duration = moment.duration(leftTime, 'seconds');

        sessionCountdownTimerOutput();
    }

    function updateUserSession() {
        // on first load, animate_images.isRunning is undefined,
        //     so (!animate_images.isRunning) returns true.
        if(!updateUserSession.isRunning) {
            /* launch animation */;
            // define animate_images.isRunning and assign true
            updateUserSession.isRunning = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                global: false,
                url: '{{url('/session/api/details')}}',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    eventTime = response;
                    setInterval(sessionCountdownTimer, 1000);
                    //sessionCountdownTimer(response);
                    updateUserSession.isRunning = false;
                },
            });
        } else {
            console.log('already running session check');
            /* animation already initialized */
        }
    }

    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
        updateUserSession();
    });
```

I have been over this and over the documentation but I can't figure out the best practice to only fire the reload script once.

Comment: `clearInterval` takes a parameter. You keep creating new intervals.

Comment: You clearInterval clear nothing use var something = setInterval(code) and then you can clearInterval(something);